# Need help troubleshooting Apache inside VM

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2

I'm hitting a wall troubleshooting this. I feel the problem is either due to my lack of networking skills, or a basic knowledge of configuring Apache. I'm hoping I can shed some light on my setup by describing my workflow.

I have a remote Ubuntu Server 12.04 VM which I access via SSH as such: `ssh username@111.111.111.111 port 1234`.

I've got apache2 running and I've confirmed so because `netstat -tulpn` shows that `apache2` is listening on `0.0.0.0:80`. And indeed apache2 is running as a process if I run `ps`. Additionally, running `wget localhost` downloads the apache's "It works!"  HTML file.

Problem is when I go to my local computer, and open up `http://111.111.111.111:1234`, I get the following errors:

Firefox: `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1`

Chrome: `This webpage is not available... Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.`

Comment: Why are you trying to open up port 1234 in the browser? You state that apache is running on port 80.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the network is setup so that port 80 on 111.111.111.111 is being forwarded to a different VM. So port 1234 is my Ubuntu machine in the 111.111.111.111 network.

Comment: Your configuration sounds confusing and you can not run ssh and http both on port 1234 at the same time. Does http://111.111.111.111 work ? Your problem is almost certainly with your port forwarding configuration.

Comment: Agreed. The message you're seeing in Firefox coming from OpenSSL. It's the crazy network setup causing the problems, not Apache.

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel I'm making progress in identifying the problem just by discussing it here. @bodhi.zazen makes a good point, I am using 1234 to ssh into my ubuntu vm. So just to see if I understand this correctly: I need another dedicated port, say 1235, which forwards to my vm's port 80. So then to invoke apache, I'll have to go to http://111.111.111.111:1235. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, AND you have to configure Apache to listen on port 1235. IMO it is usually easier to go with the default ports, so IMO just forward port 80.

Comment: I can't use port 80 in this case. I believe 111.111.111.111:80 is already being forwarded to another VM running a web server. So I definitely have to ask for a dedicated port, and have HTTP requests to that port forwarded to my VM's apache. Now I believe you mentioned that I have to configure my apache to listen to that dedicated port?

Answer (score 0):

you can not reach other ports trough your web browser, only port 80. all other are blocked for server security. first be sure that you have installed ssh on your server. if not so, type:

sudo tasksel

select ssh server from list. also:

sudo apt-get install tasksel

if not installed tasksel.

then find some remote control program, i dont know which one, there is just about milion available today, that you can select whichever you like. also check firewall status to make sure that port 22 is not blocked:

sudo ufw status